# Update collection view after computing view models in background

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

I receive data items from my API, on a specific serial queue, that I use to calculate the view models to display in a collection view. The simplified code is:

```
var viewModels: [ViewModel] = []    // read and written on main queue
var _viewModels: [ViewModel] = []   // written in background, read in main queue

func didReceive(items: [Item]) {
    // called on the same background serial queue
    _viewModels = items.map { ViewModel($0) }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.viewModels = self._viewModels
        self.updateCollectionView {
            // UI update has finished
        }
    }
}
```

`didReceive` can be called at any time.
`_viewModels` is written always on the same background queue. After that I switch to main queue to cache the computed view models and use it in data source for displaying.

Can `self.viewModels = self._viewModels` lead to crashes? Do I have to use some kind of locking mechanism? If yes, how does it work when main thread is involved?

Comment: When you dispatch event on main queue it is queued on main queue and nothing else is executed on main queue at the same time (this is the same for any queue). The risk in your approach is that (while main queue is high priority) the _viewModels be updated in background while it is copied in viewModels in main queue . Depending on how your app run it may not likely to happen. Using the _viewModels does not seems necessary as you could do the update in main queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashes not necessarily, but this can lead to inconsistency. As `_viewModels` is declared outside the scope of `didReceive`, it is a shared resource that can be modified each time you enter `didReceive`. After dispatching this to the main thread, some other thread can enter in `didReceive` and change your value. So when you assign it to `self.viewModels`, you would get the "second" value.

I believe that declaring `_viewModels` inside `didReceive` would fix your issue, as you would have a reference for each run of `didReceive`:

```swift
var viewModels: [ViewModel] = []    // read and written on main queue

func didReceive(items: [Item]) {
    // called on the same background serial queue
    let _viewModels = items.map { ViewModel($0) }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.viewModels = _viewModels
        self.updateCollectionView {
            // UI update has finished
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not allowed to do this, try taking a look at Actors:
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/actors/